# Retrieve information from old .plt files without the .dwg?

Tags: autocad, data-retrieval

I have received several .plt files dating back to 1995-2002, unfortunately there isn't any .DWG files or other files with them. They have apparently been deleted, so only the .plt files remain.

Is it possible to retrieve information from these files in anyway? They contain information about roads and their drainage systems which I would like to digitize afterwards.

I can upload a sample file if needed.

I have access to a lot of different Bentley and Autodesk software, so feel free to suggest any solution possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link from the Autodesk site that may help you.  All versions of AutoCAD should be able to plot the files for you.  [Working with PLT files](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-6405BB6F-4350-4F0A-AC09-3E237F20FBD6-htm.html)